# Android, push message when app runs?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

im developing a app in android. I want to send a push message when the client app is currently running. how can i achieve this with Google cloud messaging. or any other methods? but i want to send the push message at app running stage as well as the app closed. thanks in advance. hope someone will help me...

Answer (score 1):

delay_while_idle attribute in gcm message will make GCM Server send message when device is not idling.

Read about cloud messaging it will help to fully understand how this service works. http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: thanks buddy. im wondered!!! is it really sends the push message, when the app is running?

Comment: @Amarnath from googles reference. // delay_while_idle If included, indicates that the message should not be sent immediately if the device is idle. The server will wait for the device to become active, and then only the last message for each collapse_key value will be sent. Optional. The default value is false, and must be a JSON boolean.

Comment: but Maxim, i need to send the message in both cases. i.e. app is running and closing..

Comment: the above method only sends when app is running.

Comment: @Amarnath that attribute set to true will send message only when device is running, but if attribute is false GCM server will send message right away regardless if device running or sleeping. On a client side (Android app) broadcast from GCM will wake up device and do whatever you told it to do. But lock wake until your task is done and after release wake to let device go to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot push message on the client side.
You can send REST HTTP data to a server.

On server side - use gcm-server library for pushing gcm messages.

Comment: yes. i know. thanks for your reply. but how can i achieve this from the server side?

Comment: Whats mean archive?Zip archieve?You can add 4kb message(bytes) to a "Data" json key of the gcm message.Say more details

Comment: i said "achieve". how can i implement this in server side for sending the push notification when the app in running?

Comment: Send http request to a server that your app is running,then send gcm message from a server by com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender class